# Jenkins with kubernetes on GKE

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm new to kubernetes in combination with jenkins. Therefor I've done some tutorials.

My goal is:
1) build docker images
2) push docker images to GCR
3) deploy image in kubernetes

I've setup my GKE 1:1 like the tutorial.
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-jenkins-container-engine
Also did these tutorials:
"jenkins-on-container-engine-tutorial"
"configuring-jenkins-container-engine"

Since these tutorials are depending on each other I've done them multiple times completely from scratch to avoid errors from my side.

The issue is the build agent can't find the docker command!
I've also tried some custom images like in this thread:
[Easiest way to do docker build command within Jenkinsfile running on Jenkins slave node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493924/easiest-way-to-do-docker-build-command-within-jenkinsfile-running-on-jenkins-sla)

But nothing seems to work :(

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please post at least a portion of the code/script running on the build agent and the error message you are seeing.

Comment: Hi, I've just added a plain simple build job. Basically it's just a shell "docker -v" to check if the command is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running on GKE, so I also needed the gcloud cli which also provides docker commands.

So here are the steps:
1) create custom Jenkins image with gcloud cli installed
2) Be sure to enable the scope "cloud plattform"
3) use gcloud docker  command :)