# Docker-compose inside jenkins slave - Kubernetes Pod

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, docker-compose

I'm following this tutorial 
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-jenkins-kubernetes-engine
trying to cread CD/CI in google cloud platform. 
I use docker-compose to build the container but I'm stuck because I'm not able to have the docker-compose installed in the jenkins slave. 
I'm able to run docker inside (following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493924/easiest-way-to-do-docker-build-command-within-jenkinsfile-running-on-jenkins-sla)) using the second approach but I don't know ho to include docker-compose there.

Thanks

Comment: Where's Kubernetes?

Comment: Kubernetes is in the google cloud.

Comment: And you're talking about Docker Compose.. you probably don't want that when you have K8s.